# MicrosoftDevicePortalWrapper UploadFileAsync error

Tags: c#, uwp, hololens

I develop UWP app. This application connects Hololens and Desktop. I use MicrosoftDevicePortalWrapper nuget packages. 
https://github.com/Microsoft/WindowsDevicePortalWrapper/blob/master/GettingStarted.md
https://github.com/Microsoft/WindowsDevicePortalWrapper

UploadFileAsync method always throw this exception "This IRandomAccessStream does not support the GetInputStream method because it requires cloning and this stream does not support cloning."
I use everything as described in the documentation. Always throws this bug when you enter the filePath.

Here my code

```
public async Task<bool> SaveFiles(string userName, string password, string url, string filePath)
{
    try
    {
        DevicePortal portal = new DevicePortal(new DefaultDevicePortalConnection(url, userName, password));
        await portal.ConnectAsync();
        await portal.UploadFileAsync("LocalAppData", filePath, "LocalState", "4ab51c0b-cfe9-4548-a3b0-ca8db55bbfd2_1.0.0.0_x86__3ygapy8kah9j6");
        return true;
    }
    catch (COMException)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the `filePath` you are using? Could you share a [mcve] that can reproduce your issue?

Comment: The problem was resolved. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: I downloaded solution from the Github and i added my own solution. Nuget Packed not worked. UniversalWindows project-> HttpRest->RestPost.cs edited PostAsync method. Problem was requestContent = new HttpStreamContent(requestStream.AsInputStream())
this changed 
byte[] bytes = ReadFully(requestStream);
requestContent = new HttpBufferContent(bytes.AsBuffer());

Comment: Since you've found the solution, I'd suggest you write a answer so that others who have the same issue can find it easily. Please feel to [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).